# How to use a paired bluetooth device as Smart Lock trusted device?

Tags: bluetooth, smart-lock

I am interested in using my Nexus Player (or other bluetooth device) as a Smart Lock trusted device for my phone. My goal was to be able to unlock my device without needing my usual pin while sitting on the couch. It seems like my Nexus Player (which never moves from under my TV) is a good candidate for that.

When I navigate to *Settings* -> *Security* -> *Smart Lock* -> *Trusted devices* -> *Bluetooth*, I can see it listed, but not connected:

[image: IMG:]
<sup>**Trusted devices not connected**   (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

The devices are paired (but not connected):

[image: IMG:]
<sup>**Paired bluetooth devices**   (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Is there any way to use these as Smart Lock trusted devices?

Comment: I think you need to have a device actively connected in order to select it on the Smart Lock menu. Have you given that a try?

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes, that is true but how do you actively connect them is the issue. I've three devices with Android 4.2, 4.4 and 5.0 version They are all paired to each other, in 100 cm range and bluetooth with discovery enabled, but I don't see anywhere written something as "connected". In lollipop contrast to 4.2 and 4.4, you can touch the paired device to connect but its not working either.  I've the similar issue as the questioner have here.

Comment: @Firelord That seems like a separate issue from the Smart Lock thing, really. Many paired devices connect automatically when in range (the receiver in my car does this, for example) but I don't know how all devices work. Typically with phones and other smart devices I'd have to manually "connect" them for some purpose, like transferring files or tethering, but they won't connect automatically otherwise. From the screenshot it's not clear that the devices are physically in range at the time it was taken; paired devices are always listed regardless of their range/status.

Comment: So maybe the real question is "how to connect these devices?". Should I just modify this question or close and create a new one?

Answer (score 6):

I managed to "trick" it into connecting by sending a file from one device to another. Then it becomes available to add as a trusted device. So I think you need to be actively doing something with the intended device in order for it to be "connected"

Your car does this because your car expects to receive data from your phone. Maybe you can use bluetooth to control the device you want to connect to?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 4, same thing. I also installed "Bluetooth Auto Connect", and enabled my token device to be the first. (Otherwise it tried to connect to all the devices in order.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the device needs to be connected.  Most devices simply need you to press the blue button (or whatever makes a blue light flash).  Then in the setup...Bluetooth screen make sure it is scanning for devices.  If necessary, turn Bluetooth off then back on to force a scan.

When it finds the device it will first show an address (not the name) and you can tap on it to start the pairing.

Then when you ask for it to be trusted it will prompt you for a security code.

For many devices the code is 0000 or 00000

Here is an article that discusses the issue in detail:

[How to setup Trusted Devices on Android Lollipop to automatically unlock your phone or tablet](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/android-lollipop-guides/how-to-setup-trusted-devices-on-android-lollipop-to-automatically-unlock-your-phone-or-tablet/)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice to send a file from my laptop to my phone via bluetooth, and yes, then SmartLock was able to connect to my laptop.